# Is it safe to pass xml document as an parameter of store procedure in SqlServer?

Tags: c#, sql, xml

Need I do some additional checks before passing xml in store procedure (using c#)?

Comment: It depends on your scenario. What exactly you want to do with this xml and what kind of vulnerability are you expecting?

Comment: I am beginner and not well-informed about security issues in sql server. But i want to create an educational app in which user can export statistics from local database in xml document and vice versa - import it from xml to database. Need I take into consideration this question in such situation? Sorry for my English.

Comment: I wouldn't bother about possible security issues in the scenario you've described. Saving DB information to xml as well as parsing this xml and modifying DB data can be considered as safe actions which does not require any additional checks.

Comment: If in doubt, always use parameters for each variable.. It may take more time, but it could cost a whole lot more time, effort and money if someone exploits a flaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what exactly you are going to do, there are only general ideas:

Passing XML from a C# application to a stored procedure means transfering a string. This string is casted to XML in the moment it enters your SP (if the parameters declaration is `XML`). As long as your XML is valid, this should work.

1) If you want to make sure that this string cannot be changed on the way: You might create a hash code in your application and check against this hashcode within your SP. This hash code might be embedded into the XML, or transfered as an additional parameter or transfered in an extra process together with an ID to get extra security.

2) You want to make sure, that the XML is valid: This needs no extra effort, as long as you use "real" XML objects in C# and do not create the XML with a StringBuilder or similar.

3) You want to make sure, that your XML follows a dedicated schema: Use an XSD to check if your XML is structurally fullfilling a "contract". You might do this in your application, or in SQL Server or both.

Comment: No strings here: `using (var reader = myXml.CreateReader()) {               command.Parameters.Add("@xmlParam", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = new SqlXml(reader); }`

Comment: @adrianm I'm quite sure (but not 100%), that the XML is typesafe on c# side, and typesafe within the SP, but is serialized to a string in the middle. I would not assume, that a change to the passed over string was recognized. If you create a typed DataSet from a table with an XML column the type within the c# DataSet is `string`. As I said: I'm *quite* sure, that XML is string somewhere in between ...

Comment: You can be 100% sure, Its serialized to a string in the call generated by the `SQLCommand` object, you would see: `declare @p1 xml; set @p1=convert(xml,N'<a></a>'); exec sp_Whatever @p1` actually sent to the server, the XML string in the convert call is properly `'` escaped. Malformed XML generates an exception here (`convert()` fails), before it even reaches the sp.

Comment: @AlexK. Thx, I did not expect something else... It was a - quite academic -  thinking about security issues. The OP stated in a comment, that it was this he wanted to know. If someone would change the serialized XML on  the way between the application and the SP (and there it is kind of a string) I would not think, that this is recognized. That's why I suggested creating a hash code to check if the XML is the same here and there.